# C# doesn't inject c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll-injection

I tried to make my own simple dll injector on c# which injects a c++ dll. When I run it doesn't throw me any errors.

I think the dll just doesn't execute in the process or it doesn't inject properly.

I'm on windows 8.

Code:

```
public void Injector(string dll)
    {

        try
        {
            IntPtr allocMem = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dll.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            UIntPtr bytesWritten;
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, allocMem, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dll), (uint)((dll.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), out bytesWritten);

            CreateRemoteThread(pHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, Libaddr, allocMem, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
       
    }
```

Full code:
https://pastebin.com/LRNhfzMc

Comment: the obvious point is that you are not testing the return values of the various API calls you are making. pinvoke will not throw on a bad return from an API cal, you have to test yourself

Comment: You are simply writing your dll into some process's memory. That shouldn't be right. That's why there are functions like LoadLibrary. There are many more things that must be done before code can work.

Comment: You can however do the classical way: write your dll's path into the process memory;then create  thread with LoadLibrary as entry point and pass it the path to your dll. There are numerous tutorials about how to achieve that thrown all over  the place (internet)

Comment: Well, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set values to the members IntPtr pHandle; and IntPtr Libaddr; in your injector class.

Change your constructor to this:

```
    public injector(string proc_name)
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc_name)[0];
        Console.WriteLine("pId: "+proc.Id);
        pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, proc.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Proc handle: "+ pHandle.ToString());
        Libaddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    }
```

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work. I tried to debug it and all functions do their work and return values. Similar injector using similar functions but written on c++ works properly. How to understand this?